# Property of coprime integer.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, coprime

I am trying to prove the following elementary property (which I guess should be true):

Given 2 coprime positive integers $a, b$, we have $a\mathbb Z/b\mathbb Z = \mathbb Z/b\mathbb Z.$

Is the following proof correct? Is there a much faster way to show it?

I know that $(a, b)=1$ implies that there are integers $u$ and $v$ such that $ua+vb = 1$. In particular $ua =1 \bmod b$. Now essentially we need to show that
$$\{a\bmod b, 2a\bmod b, \dots, ba\bmod b\}=\{0,1,\dots, b-1\}\,.$$
This will be true if the LHS has cardinality $b$. So if it does not hold there must be two integers $i\neq j$ in $\{0,1,\dots, b-1\}$ such that $ia = ja\bmod b$. In particular $(i-j)a=0\bmod b$. But then $0 = (i-j)ua = i-j\bmod b$, meaning that $i=j$ as they are both in $\{0,1,\dots, b-1\}$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: You don't need contradiction. $a\mathbb Z/b\mathbb Z\subset\mathbb Z/b\mathbb Z$ since $a\mathbb Z\subset\mathbb Z$. And, $uka\equiv k\bmod b$ for all $k\in\mathbb Z$, so all elements of $Z/b\mathbb Z$ are in $a\mathbb Z/b\mathbb Z$.

Comment: True! Thank you!